# C++ stl::map find with structs

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have struct that store info about ARP packet and I need to save the ARP request and reply packet together. I would like to use std::map for this, the key and mapped value is that ARP struct, and I would be using the find operator to math the reply with request.

My question is how can I say map::find to compare only some members from struct.

Example of what I'm trying to describe

```
struct arp_packet : public packet_info
{
    u_short type;   // 0x0001 request
                    // 0x0002 reply

    struct ipv4_address ip_sender;
    struct ipv4_address ip_target;
};
```

I would save all request in map like this

```
std::map<arp_packet*, arp_packet*>
```

First the mapped value is NULL but whet the reply packet comes I will use the find method to match it to request.

So how should I accomplist that the map would take as key the arp_packet *, and in find it would take the another arp_packet * and match it using ip_sender and ip_target?

Comment: Since you're storing raw pointers, you simply need to provide a predicate that provides an appropriate less-than comparison for type `arp_packet*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `std::map` accepts up to 4 template parameters (the last 2 have default values).

You would be using the 3rd parameter here: a functor meant to compare two keys.

```
struct ArpComparator {
  bool operator()(arp_packet* const left, arp_packet* const right) {
    // compare the fields you need here
  }
};

typedef std::map<arp_packet*, arp_packet*, ArpComparator> ArpMap;
```

Be careful about implementing a proper `operator()` semantics, it should match the mathematical properties of `<`, notably *antisymmetry* and *transitivity*.

Comment: I tried this but it isn't doing what i want
Maybe the map is not suited for this problem.
What I want is to first insert into some container an arp_packet* and then if the reply comes looks in this container for its request counterpart.

Comment: @Jan: unfortunately, since I have no idea how you actually identify the `request` packet from the `reply` one, it's kinda hard to answer. It seems though that you do not really need a mapping here, merely a searchable container, you could try `std::set<arp_packet*, ArpComparator>` to hold onto the request packets waiting for a reply.

Comment: Also tried the std::set approach however it also don't work as I want, but I think that I will use eventually use map and I will calculate simple hash from the packet and use that as a key. I need to bound reply to request base on ipv4 addresses and since ipv4 use 32 bit to represent the address I will use unsigned long as hash.
in request the 0-31 bit will be ip target and 32-63 ip sender, in reply the order will be reverse.
But thanks for informations about map and the comparator

Comment: @Jan: the number of bits in `unsigned long` is implementation defined and depends on the platform, better use `uint32_t` from the C header `<stdint.h>`. You could use that as the map key, by the way: `std::map<uint32_t, arp_packet*>`.

Comment: That's a good point, however uint32_t is not enough, uint64_t on the other hand is what it needs. Thanks.